# Obtener el valor de una variable que está dentro de un addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que me permite obtener el valor de una celda de una tabla, pero quisiera guardarla en una variable PHP.

El problema es que al estar dentro de un `for`, me muestra varias veces el valor obtenido. Ya intenté declarando la variable (`b`) afuera del `for` y no pasa el valor.

Adjunto el código JavaScript.

```
<script>

function gg()
{
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButton');
    for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){

            var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent;
            alert(b);
        }
        );
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Consulta, el botton es parte de cada item de tu tabla? Puedes dejar el codigo de tu tabla?

Comment: @jota ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML para entender a qué estás haciendo referencia, qué elementos tienen esa clase y cuáles son los parentNodes?

Comment: @sioesi el botón si es parte, adjunto un capture:  http://imgur.com/a/zcwRc  el boton con signo de dolar.

Comment: solo como duda, como carga usted los datos de la tabla? Es un foreach que va cargando dependiendo de un array o algo asi?

Comment: ahi le adjunto la capture de como carga los datos en la tabla:  http://imgur.com/FuXz7pR

Comment: @jota debajo de tu pregunta, está el enlace para [edit]. Ahí podrás agregar todo el detalle para que puedan ayudarte, de lo contrario es imposible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te recomiendo que pongas el codigo en tu pregunta y no con imagenes, asi mas usuarios pueden ayudarte. Tu ejemplo es facil!

Tus botones tiene una clase `otherButton`, lo que puedes hacer es darles un tag a esos buttons que vas creando en tu ciclo while, ejemplo

```
$pago = '<a href="#" class="otherButton" id_gen_pago="'.$id_gen_pago.'">'
```

Y con el js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.otherButton').click(function() {
    var id_gen_pago = $(this).data('id_gen_pago');
    alert('id gen pago:' + id_gen_pago )
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres usar jQuery puedes hacerlo simplemente añadiendo el valor de la celda al atributo nativo **id** del elemento  y luego recuperar lo en el bucle simplemente con **this.id**. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<a href="#" class="otherButton" id="10">Link 10</a>

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButton');
  for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      alert(this.id);
  });
}
```